# how do Major number and minor numbers used to locate file operation for drivers?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am beginner at the device driver....

I would like to know how the file operations are located from device files and drivers using major and minor numbers ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. If it's programming related, you may need to go to Stackoverflow. Please add more details.

Comment: Actually it is not related to programming.....I just want to know what are the back-end steps taken to do file operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're learning to program Linux device drivers, I should tell you there's a free ebook on the topic.

[Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

[LDD3 Chapter 3: Char Drivers](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf)

Our answers should provide more than just links.  So here's a relevant extract.

> ```
> crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Apr 11 2002 null
> crw------- 1 root root 10, 1 Apr 11 2002 psaux
> crw------- 1 root root 4, 1 Oct 28 03:04 tty1
> crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 4, 64 Apr 11 2002 ttys0
> crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 4, 65 Apr 11 2002 ttyS1
> crw--w---- 1 vcsa tty 7, 1 Apr 11 2002 vcs1
> crw--w---- 1 vcsa tty 7, 129 Apr 11 2002 vcsa1
> crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Apr 11 2002 zero
> ```
>
> Traditionally, the major number identifies the driver associated with the device. For
>   example,
>   /dev/null
>   and
>   /dev/zero
>   are both managed by driver 1, whereas virtual con-
>   soles and serial terminals are managed by driver 4; similarly, both
>   vcs1
>   and
>   vcsa1
>   devices are managed by driver 7. Modern Linux kernels allow multiple drivers to
>   share major numbers, but most devices that you will see are still organized on the
>   one-major-one-driver principle.
>
> The minor number is used by the kernel to determine exactly which device is being
>   referred to. Depending on how your driver is written (as we will see below), you can
>   either get a direct pointer to your device from the kernel, or you can use the minor
>   number yourself as an index into a local array of devices. Either way, the kernel itself
>   knows almost nothing about minor numbers beyond the fact that they refer to
>   devices implemented by your driver.

Comment: Thank you ....Its helpful....Can you tell me how kernel will differ the driver with the same major number ?

Comment: Keep reading.  "int register_chrdev_region(dev_t first, unsigned int count,
char *name);
Here,
first
is the beginning device number of the range you would like to allocate.
__The minor number portion of
first
is often
0
, but there is no requirement to that
effect__